# Read id from directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can output only the 'id' of 'response' in this dic?

I would like to write the whole thing in a text file afterwards. it should look like this.

unfortunately response['id'] is wrong

```
def write_to_file(ids):
    file = open('id.txt', 'a')
    file.write(ids + '\n')
    file.close()

response = [{'items': [{'track': {'id': '6gaeewGjNiQhWOUkWRSLTa'}}, {'track': {'id': '0TK2YIli7K1leLovkQiNik'}}, {'track': {'id': '6v0lAdFF4haL8xjBIUjtOw'}}, {'track': {'id': '443cnFF139Ql85enXOTWEu'}}, {'track': {'id': '7bBIBrSmHvdMlTC7b9p8Vq'}}, {'track': {'id': '50Ud3ecSw6hsVlmAECRuBV'}}, {'track': {'id': '0sjSgTluUJIdqfyRe4EQ4U'}}, {'track': {'id': '2TfcMUAZ4vH4fTA9eF53v2'}}, {'track': {'id': '0YOUE1TlkgSbkNvWkZkEVp'}}, {'track': {'id': '5itHWf2i5yo9PM9bgq4hmP'}}, {'track': {'id': '3AKm9sJmK0v3wUQYSLuze7'}}]}]

print(response['id'])
write_to_file(response['id'])
```

the file should look like this here id.txt :

```
 6gaeewGjNiQhWOUkWRSLTa
 6v0lAdFF4haL8xjBIUjtOw
 443cnFF139Ql85enXOTWEu
 7bBIBrSmHvdMlTC7b9p8Vq
 50Ud3ecSw6hsVlmAECRuBV
 0sjSgTluUJIdqfyRe4EQ4U
 2TfcMUAZ4vH4fTA9eF53v2
 0YOUE1TlkgSbkNvWkZkEVp
 5itHWf2i5yo9PM9bgq4hmP
 3AKm9sJmK0v3wUQYSLuze7
```

Comment: `response` is a **`list`**, not a `dict`, which is why you cannot index it with a string like `'id'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You structure is much complex than accessing `id` directly.

- you have a `list` of `dict`
- each `dict` has a `items` key that points to a `list`
- the `list` is `list` of `dict`
- each `dict` contains a `track` key that points to a `dict`
- that `dict` has the `id` key that points to the value you want

Using a `list-comprehension` it looks like

```
ids = [item['track']['id'] for items in response for item in items['items']]
```

---

You need some change on the `write_to_file` method to write the list too

```
def write_to_file(ids):
    with open('id.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write("\n".join(ids) + '\n')


response = [{'items': [{'track': {'id': '6gaeewGjNiQhWOUkWRSLTa'}}, {'track': {'id': '0TK2YIli7K1leLovkQiNik'}},
                       {'track': {'id': '6v0lAdFF4haL8xjBIUjtOw'}}, {'track': {'id': '443cnFF139Ql85enXOTWEu'}},
                       {'track': {'id': '7bBIBrSmHvdMlTC7b9p8Vq'}}, {'track': {'id': '50Ud3ecSw6hsVlmAECRuBV'}},
                       {'track': {'id': '0sjSgTluUJIdqfyRe4EQ4U'}}, {'track': {'id': '2TfcMUAZ4vH4fTA9eF53v2'}},
                       {'track': {'id': '0YOUE1TlkgSbkNvWkZkEVp'}}, {'track': {'id': '5itHWf2i5yo9PM9bgq4hmP'}},
                       {'track': {'id': '3AKm9sJmK0v3wUQYSLuze7'}}]}]

ids = [item['track']['id'] for items in response for item in items['items']]

print(ids)
# ['6gaeewGjNiQhWOUkWRSLTa', '0TK2YIli7K1leLovkQiNik', '6v0lAdFF4haL8xjBIUjtOw', '443cnFF139Ql85enXOTWEu', 
# '7bBIBrSmHvdMlTC7b9p8Vq', '50Ud3ecSw6hsVlmAECRuBV', '0sjSgTluUJIdqfyRe4EQ4U', '2TfcMUAZ4vH4fTA9eF53v2', 
# '0YOUE1TlkgSbkNvWkZkEVp', '5itHWf2i5yo9PM9bgq4hmP', '3AKm9sJmK0v3wUQYSLuze7']

write_to_file(ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like this:

```py
def write_to_file(ids):
    file = open('id.txt', 'a')
    for id in ids:
        file.write(id + '\n')
    file.close()


response = [{'items': [
                          {'track': {'id': '6gaeewGjNiQhWOUkWRSLTa'}},
                          {'track': {'id': '0TK2YIli7K1leLovkQiNik'}},
                          {'track': {'id': '6v0lAdFF4haL8xjBIUjtOw'}},
                          {'track': {'id': '443cnFF139Ql85enXOTWEu'}},
                          {'track': {'id': '7bBIBrSmHvdMlTC7b9p8Vq'}},
                          {'track': {'id': '50Ud3ecSw6hsVlmAECRuBV'}},
                          {'track': {'id': '0sjSgTluUJIdqfyRe4EQ4U'}},
                          {'track': {'id': '2TfcMUAZ4vH4fTA9eF53v2'}},
                          {'track': {'id': '0YOUE1TlkgSbkNvWkZkEVp'}},
                          {'track': {'id': '5itHWf2i5yo9PM9bgq4hmP'}},
                          {'track': {'id': '3AKm9sJmK0v3wUQYSLuze7'}}]
           }]

items = response[0]['items']
ids = [item['track']['id'] for item in items]
write_to_file(ids)
```

First, you need to access the items in your list. This appears in the first index, and then, the 'items' key. After that you want to extract all of the ids, and write all line by line.

Output file:

```
6gaeewGjNiQhWOUkWRSLTa
0TK2YIli7K1leLovkQiNik
6v0lAdFF4haL8xjBIUjtOw
443cnFF139Ql85enXOTWEu
7bBIBrSmHvdMlTC7b9p8Vq
50Ud3ecSw6hsVlmAECRuBV
0sjSgTluUJIdqfyRe4EQ4U
2TfcMUAZ4vH4fTA9eF53v2
0YOUE1TlkgSbkNvWkZkEVp
5itHWf2i5yo9PM9bgq4hmP
3AKm9sJmK0v3wUQYSLuze7
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `response` variable is a list with a lot of dictionaries. You cannot access all the `ids` straight from the variable. Instead, do this:

```
ids = []
//looping through the tracks
for item in response[0][items]:
    ids.append(item['track']['id'])
for id in ids:
    write_to_file(id)
```